Is it allowed for User to open my App`s activity (from whatsApp or File manager ) when Intersitial Ad or App open ad is on Screen
I have a pdf reader app (android based), I am showing admob Ads in my App, when user opens a pdf file  and then press back, I'm showing Intersitial Ad on onBackPress in the DocumentViewer activity. So my question is what if user press back and Intersitial ad shows but user does not close the Ad and minimizes the App and open another file from WhatsApp or file manager then new activity instance created over the Intersitial Ad, is it voilation of Google Admob policies.
I tried different Activity launch mode, but I did not find a way to get ride of the situation.
